# GSM Modem Wavecom 900

Tags: gsm

I have one GSM Modem Series 900. I want to test it for sending and receiving message to mobile. I can connect with this modem, but when I put my SIM Card and I type AT command like here:

```
AT: Status "OK"  
AT+CPIN?: Status "+CPIN: PH-NET PIN"  
AT+CPIN="xxxx": Status "Error"
```

I don't know why it can't connect with the SIM Card. So do you any solution to help me on this problem?

Thanks,
Sopolin

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HI,

Check the end of this thread:
http://www.mail-archive.com/smartphones-standards@linuxtogo.org/msg00052.html
It seems that your modem is locked on a network, you´ll have to unlock it.
Is it second-hand or does it come from another country?

It seems that there are a lot of answers just searching for "+CPIN: PH NET PIN"

Comment: Hi Pablo, how can I unlock GSM Modem (Wavecom). Could you guide me with AT Command?

Thanks,
Sopolin

Comment: Hi, I don´t know and for the answers I´ve been reading it does seem hard. It´s te same as unblocking a cell phone to use it with other operator, not always possible.

Comment: Hi, one more thing sir, when I don't insert SIM Card in the slot. Then I type AT command: AT+CPIN?  : the message response "Error".
What is this problem?

Comment: You get an error because the SIM is not inserted. The PIN is stored on the SIM, so asking the status of the PIN with AT+CPIN? is an error.